# using tcmalloc with glib

Tags: c, memory-management, glib, tcmalloc

I want to test the performance improvement that I could get by using Google's tcmalloc. My program is built using quite a lot of the utilities provided by glib (hashes, lists, arrays, ...). So what I want is basically to make glib to use tcmalloc instead of glibc's malloc.

I could address this issue with two approaches:

1. By compiling glib with the `-tcmalloc` option.
2. by using `g_mem_set_vtable ()` from the [glib's memory allocation functions](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/unstable/glib-Memory-Allocation.html#g-mem-set-vtable).

I actually prefer the second one but I have not found any examples for implementing it.

Any hints ? Any ideas for doing this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`LD_PRELOAD` method suggested in the tcmalloc documentation](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html).

Alternatively, before using any glib functions, load the tcmalloc library using [`dlopen()`. `dlsym()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) the `malloc()`, `realloc()`, and `free()` routines, and initialize a [`struct GMemVTable`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/unstable/glib-Memory-Allocation.html#GMemVTable) with them. (Assuming the tcmalloc `calloc()` is superior, that too). Be sure to initialize members you don't use to `0` (C99 named member initialization is great for this). Lastly call [`g_mem_set_vtable()`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/unstable/glib-Memory-Allocation.html#g-mem-set-vtable)

Comment: you'd better replace calloc too or it'll crash when you free, whether it's superior doesn't much matter

Comment: No, you don't have to. Presuably glib has a memzero operation if one is not provided.

Comment: Note "TCMALLOC AND DLOPEN" section in the INSTALL file coming in gperftools. It suggests to disable Thread Local Storage before attempting to dlopen the library.